# Problema al enviar correo desde laravel

Tags: laravel, smtp

Tengo la siguiente configuracion en el archivo .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=parqueosumg@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

y mi controlador de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Parqueos;
    use App\Mail\ComentariosParqueos;
    use Mail;
    class ParqueosController extends Controller
    {
        public $message = "";
        public $result  = false;
        public $records = array();



        public function EnviarComentario()
        {
            try
            {
               $data = [];

               Mail::send('mails.ComentariosParqueos', $data, function ($message){
                    $message->subject('Comentario');
                    $message->to('parqueosumg@gmail.com');
                });

                $statusCode     = 200;
                $this->message  = "Correo enviado correctamente";
                $this->result   = true;
            }
            catch (\Exception $e)
            {
                $statusCode     = 200;
                $this->message  = $e->getMessage();
            }
            finally
            {
                $response =
                [
                    'message'   => $this->message,
                    'result'    => $this->result,
                    'records'   => $this->records
                ];
                    return response()->json($response, $statusCode);
            }
        }
    }
```

al ejecutar el metodo devuelve lo siguiente:

```
{
  "message": "Correo enviado correctamente",
  "result": true,
  "records": Array[0][

  ]
}
```

Pero resulta que no envía nada en la vista solo tengo html con el fin de hacer prueba si llega el correo.

¿Cual podrá ser mi error?

Comment: Siempre tuve problemas enviando correos usando mi propio correo gmail con laravel, te recomiendo que uses mailgun te da 10000 correos al mes de manera gratuita. Igual hay otros servicios similares. El único problema es tener un dominio para configurar los DNS

Comment: Primero es  `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp` , segundlo ya fuistes a gmail y activastes el inicio de session para aplicaciones menos segura? Y luego aceptar el correo que te envia gmail donde te pregunta que si fuistes tu quien inicio session en X dispositivo?

Comment: Utiliza como driver smtp

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente como usas mail como driver, tu correo este mal configurado en el servidor. Probaste a mandar desde el terminal un correo?

Comment: como haces eso ?

Comment: mail -s "asunto" nick@correo.com