# ¿Cómo recibir un objeto en este método que se encuentra en un controlador - laravel?

Tags: angularjs, laravel

Tengo el siguiente método que envía un correo electrónico, pero en esta ocasión dentro de la función `Mail::send`, envío un arreglo `$data`.

```
public function EnviarComentario()
    {
        try
        {
           $data = [
                "correo" => "prueba",
                "nombre" => "prueba",
                "comentario" => "Esto es una prueba de comentario"
           ];

           Mail::send('mails.ComentariosParqueos', ["data1"=>$data], function ($message){
                $message->subject('Comentario');
                $message->to('parqueosumg@gmail.com');
            });

            $statusCode     = 200;
            $this->message  = "Correo enviado correctamente";
            $this->result   = true;
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            $statusCode     = 200;
            $this->message  = $e->getMessage();
        }
        finally
        {
            $response =
            [
                'message'   => $this->message,
                'result'    => $this->result
            ];
                return response()->json($response, $statusCode);
        }
    }
```

Como podria recibir un objeto en este metodo y asi mismo enviarlo por la funcion Mail::send() a mi vista ComentariosParqueos.

Ésta es mi vista que recibe el arreglo `$data`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <strong>Has recibo un nuevo comentario: </strong>
      <ul>
          <li>Correo:  <?php echo $data1['correo']; ?></li>
          <li>Nombre:  <?php echo $data1['nombre']; ?></li>
      </ul>
      <h1>Comentario: <?php echo $data1['comentario']; ?></h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

Como recibiría y mostraría el valor de un objeto dentro de esta vista.

Este objeto lo mandaré mediante una vista que esta hecha con angularjs, usando ng-model.

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
                  <h3 class="section-heading-underline">Contáctenos</h3>
                  <form novalidate class="form-horizontal wow fadeInRight">
                    <fieldset>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="ui-input-group">
                          <input type="text" required class="form-control" ng-model="item.correo"><span class="input-bar"></span>
                          <label>Correo</label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="ui-input-group">
                          <input type="text" required class="form-control" ng-model="item.nombre"><span class="input-bar"></span>
                          <label>Nombre completo</label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="ui-input-group">
                          <textarea type="text" required rows="5" class="form-control" ng-model="item.mensaje"></textarea><span class="input-bar"></span>
                          <label>Mensaje</label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="divider"></div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-raised btn-primary btn-w-sm ui-wave" ng-click="enviarComentario(item);">Enviar</button>
                      </div>
                    </fieldset>
                  </form>
                </div>
```

Lo que esta vista envía es lo siguiente:

```
{correo: "PRUEBA", nombre: "PRUEBA", mensaje: "PRUEBA"}
```

Ésta sería la función hecha en angularjs

```
 $scope.enviarComentario = function(item){
        $scope.item = item;

       $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '../ws/comentario',
        data: item
     }).then(function (success){

     },function (error){

     });
   }
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Problema al enviar correo desde laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/115328/problema-al-enviar-correo-desde-laravel)

Comment: No entiendo algo. Tienes problemas enviando el correo o es que estas recibiendo datos desde el servidor y no sabes como mostrarlos en la vista con angularjs?

Comment: El enviar el correo está funcionando correctamente, me refiero a enviar a la vista del correo. Debo mandar un objeto que recibo con angularjs, con angular mando los datos en este caso sería que mandó el objeto

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que recuperar los datos en el controlador mediante la clase `request` no te olvides importarla mediante el `namespace`.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function EnviarComentario(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

Podras acceder a los datos enviador mediante el método `post` con el metodo `all` de la clase `request`, o acceder directamente a uno en particular.

```
dd($request->correo);
```

Para mas información revisa la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests

Comment: No importando si solo sea un objeto o un array el que recibo.